# Ya'amod by an Aliya

Tags: words, hebrew, torah-service

The root of the word Ya'amod means to stand in place. See [Hebrew dictionary here](https://milog.co.il/%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%93). Thus why do we call up someone to an Aliya with the word Ya'amod? We are not asking him to stay in place, we are asking him to come up to the Bimah? Is it not more proper to say Yavo יבא or Yailaich ילך or Ya'aleh יעלה or some other word that means to go up to the bimah rather than a word that means to stand in place?

Comment: Especially people must stand during Kriya whether or not they are the ones getting an aliya

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Almost no Rishon thought that was necessary. Do you mean 'especially according to those who hold people must...'

Comment: Presumably the language makes sense in the context of a sitting congregation. Especially if they were sitting close to the ground, the most significant component of getting to the bimma would have been the getting up.

Comment: "We are not asking him to stay in place". Well, in order to walk, one has to stand, doesn't he? And the person will be standing while the Torah is being read. So, I think the phrase is mainly after the end, or rather "most important" part that is attached to the mitzvah itself, which is the Torah reading. You're not reading the Torah while he is walking to the Bimah.

Comment: See newly posted question - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79448/5275 as well as the other related questions mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the reason we say *ya'amod* rather than *yavo* or one of your other suggestions is because we are stating the important part of what the *oleh* will be doing: standing before the Torah. Sure, you've got to walk up there in most cases but that's not the important thing. Plus, what if the guy is already standing up there? He wouldn't have to do any walking at all.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the person is being called to stand in front of the Torah and to have the aliyah. The point is that the person is being called to stand *before the king*. Since the hinr of the calling is the standing during the aliyah, then the language used refers to that.

Comment: I'm not convinced that 'before the King' is relevant. I think it's just simply telling the person to arise to to come and get his Aliya.